# Visual Studio Professional 2012 , will cause the CPU to reach 100% and the VM will hang then get restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have my development environment as follow:-

1. Visual Studio 2012 Professional. version `11.0.50727.1`
2. Windows Server 2012 R2.
3. asp.net mvc4 web application.

now since last week i am facing these problems:-

1. when i run my asp.net mvc web application inside visual studio, i will receive the following error, when i access my asp.net MVC home page:-

> ```
> 500 Internal Server Error
> ```

2. after many runs, the CPU will reaches 100% and my development machine will automatically get restarted. now i check with our system admins and they mentioned that the VM got restarted because of high CPU...

so i am not sure if the problem is within VS 2012 , or within the VM itself.. baring in mind that the VM host some test applications inside IIS,, and we can access these application without any problem. also i can open the sql managemnt studio and work with the DBs without any problem. so before asking to expand the DEV machine specifications to avoid high CPU , i want to make sure that the problem is not within Visual Studio itself ??

here is 2 screen from the server manager after the VM got restarted :-

[image]

[image]

now i am not sure how i can fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: There are many causes of 500 errors, but one possible cause if you are following these tutorials is that you put an XML element in the wrong place in one of the Web.config transformation files. For example, you would get this error if you put the transformation that inserts a <location> element under <system.web> instead of directly under <configuration>. You can use the Web.config transform preview feature to verify that transformations are working as intended. The solution if you find a transform that was coded incorrectly is to correct the transformation file and redeploy.

Comment: continuation.... If an error isn't obvious, try commenting out transforms and redeploying to see which one is causing the 500 error.

Comment: What code is running on that page load? Something is getting stuck in a loop and eventually maxing out the CPU I would guess, either in your code or in your server config like Webruster mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The 500 Server Error is the standard error report from IIS if an MVC application throws an unhandled exception. So your code inside your MVC application is faulting somehow.

If this occurs you would normally run your site in debug mode in Visual Studio to trap the exception and debug out the problem. I have not idea what your application actually does but I can speculate the following possible cause;

1) IIS receives your call.
2) The MVC code generates a high CPU load doing some faulty code.
3) The calling application times out its HTTP call, and calls again.
4) Another IIS Instance is created to deal with the new HTTP Call (depends on your IIS Setup)
5) The second IIS instance does the same as (2) but in a different thread, causing more resource consumption.

Eventually you get a 500 server error as one of your IIS instances times out or throws and exception. Your "helpful" sysadmin kills your VM.

The killing of the VM is entirely uneccessary - IIS has perfectly adequate safeguards against runaway IIS processes, including IIS Application Pool timeouts, automatic IIS Application Pool recycling, IIS Application Pool CPU Throttling, and IIS Application Pool maximum memory usage. All of these configuration options prevent the operating system from being destabilised by a runaway IIS application.

Without any insight into what your website does in the background we cannot go any further, but if you mod your question and give some of the MVC code its possible something might be spotted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with Visual Studio 2013.  The error turned out to be one my Addins.  If you are using add-ins, try disabling the suspected plugin from the Tools --> Add-in Manager..., then restart Visual Studio.  If you are using extensions try reviewing those as well from Tools --> Extensions and Updates...

You can optionally choose to run Visual Studio in Safe Mode which will essentially do the same thing but will disable all plugins.  `devenv.exe /SafeMode`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issue in Windows Server 2012 running Visual studio 2012.

Upgrade your Visual studio and Windows server both. It will solve the issue